# How to validate whether a string-value is a parsable date-format?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, validation, parsing

I am running the code below, checking if the string is a date. One of my input values is `'text'` which returns the `NaN` value but my `if` clause does not work as expected.

```js
function isDate(myDate) {
  console.log('myDate = ' + myDate);
  return Date.parse(new Date(myDate));
}

// var date1 = '1/5/22'; // good date
var date1 = 'test'; // bad date

var whatDate = isDate(date1);

console.log('date = ' + whatDate);

if (whatDate == 'NaN') {
  console.log('bad date');
} else {
  console.log('good date');
}
```

Comment: `NaN` isn't a string. Use `Number.isNaN(whatDate)`

Comment: A check  or test function especially if it is also carries the prefix `is` in its name should always return exclusively a boolean value. Thus the OP firstly would implement such a function in a way a user would expect it to work. Secondly the OP has do deal withe the `NaN` issue exactly once within the test function's implementation.

Comment: In `Date.parse(new Date(myDate))` either *Date.parse* or *new Date* is redundant. You should never leave parsing to the built–in parser unless you know the value is a format supported by ECMA-262 (essentially ISO 8601 or the format produced by *toString*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
if(whatDate == 'NaN'){
    log.debug('bad date');
}else{
    log.debug('good date');
}
```

Instead of comparing `whatDate` to `'NaN'` use the function [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```
if(isNaN(whatDate)){
    log.debug('bad date');
}else{
    log.debug('good date');
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to compare to `'NaN'` you first have to convert `whatDate` to a string:

```
if((whatDate + "") == 'NaN'){
    log.debug('bad date');
}else{
    log.debug('good date');
}
```

Is one possibility. Another way would be

```
if(whatDate.toString() == 'NaN'){
    log.debug('bad date');
}else{
    log.debug('good date');
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the result of `new Date(NaN).toString()`. It's not "NaN".

Answer (score 2):

in your if statement you are checking if whatDate is equal to string "NaN". what you want to check whether whatDate is a number or not.

you can try

```
if (isNaN(whatDate))
```

Comment: `whatDate === NaN` This won't work because `NaN` is special, in that, `NaN` will never equal itself (`NaN === NaN` gives `false`).

Comment: seems like it. I checked in console :D and edited it. never had to write NaN == NaN

Answer (score 0):

The following answer, in addition to what already was explained about how to detect a `NaN` value, wants to reach further.

A check or test function especially if it also carries the **prefix `is`** in its name **should always return exclusively a *boolean* value**.

- Thus the OP firstly would implement such a function in a way a user would expect it to work.
- Secondly the OP had do **deal with the `NaN` issue exactly once** within the test function's implementation.

---

***Edit** according and thanks to the clarification of **RobG***

**... and ...** according to the ECMAScript's spec with [instantiating a `Date` object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date), the argument passed to the constructor function will be parsed and assigned to the internal `thisTimeValue` slot. The number type of the latter is the `NaN` value for a non parsable (invalid) argument.

Any `valueOf` related operation does return the value of the internal `thisTimeValue` slot.

Any `toString` related operation will compute a date string format from the latter value. For a `thisTimeValue` of `NaN` the returned string value has to be `'Invalid Date'`.

Thus a validation / test implementation could have been something like ...

```
function isParsableDateRepresentative(...args) {
  return String(new Date(...args)) !== 'Invalid Date';
}
```

... but preferably it should be closer to the next provided one ...

```
function isParsableDateRepresentative(...args) {
  return !Number.isNaN(new Date(...args).valueOf());
}
```

Tests:

```js
function isParsableDateRepresentative(...args) {
  return !Number.isNaN(new Date(...args).valueOf());
}

console.log('new Date("1/5/22") ...', new Date("1/5/22"));
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative("1/5/22") ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative("1/5/22")
);
console.log('\nnew Date("test") ...', new Date("test"));
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative("test") ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative("test")
);
console.log('\nnew Date(new Date("test")) ...', new Date(new Date("test")));
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative(new Date("test")) ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative(new Date("test"))
);

console.log('\nnew Date() ...', new Date());
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative() ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative()
);
console.log('\nnew Date(null) ...', new Date(null));
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative(null) ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative(null)
);
console.log('\nnew Date(undefined) ...', new Date(undefined));
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative(undefined) ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative(undefined)
);
console.log('\nnew Date("") ...', new Date(""));
console.log(
  'isParsableDateRepresentative("") ...',
  isParsableDateRepresentative("")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Re "*the return value is a Date object with an internal string value of 'Invalid Date'*" Nope. Date objects only have one internal value, which is a number that is a valid [*time value*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) or *NaN*, it's not a string. The string "Invalid Date" is produced by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) if the *time value* is *NaN*.

Comment: PS, `String(new Date(...args)) !== 'Invalid Date';` would be much simpler as `isNaN(new Date(...args))`. However, the fact that a string is parsed to a valid time value does not mean it was parsed correctly, or that it was a valid date, or that the same string will be parsed to the same time value in other implementations. :-)

Comment: @RobG ... Thanks for clarifying, I've falsely believed for many years, that a `Date` instance always internally already features both representatives as values, the `thisTimeValue` number type (which would be returned with e.g. `valueOf`) and the corresponding string value of the abstract `ToDateString` operation. But i was wrong. Any `toString` related return value gets computed at the spot.

Comment: @RobG ... I edited/corrected my answer according to your clarification(s). Thanks again for having pointed to my lack of understanding in a truly professional way.